# Spring Rest Service getting 400 Bad Request after running 2-3 minutes

Tags: spring, rest

I have a rest client and server which we have developed using spring.  The client will send requests to the server for 2-3 minutes and then starts getting org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request errors.

Once the 400 error starts the client is unable to communicate with the server.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I will try to develop a working example that creates this error.

I have resolved this issue.  The code was setting the following for every call:

```
    // Add the Gson message converter
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

I moved this code to the constructor and no longer getting the 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: We can't do anything without details. Is the request changing after 2-3 minutes?

Comment: There are two different requests being sent at the same time.  The client sends the two requests and then sleeps for 1 seconds and repeats.  '

Comment: I am currently working on something that I can share.

Comment: How can I add an zip as an attachment?

Comment: I have a test project that creates the problems:http://www.filedropper.com/resttestapp

Comment: The zip is a eclipse/maven project.  The project contains both the server, which runs in tomcat under eclipse.  The client is there and is used via a test class.  Just start tomcat with the server and then start the test client.  I will run for a few minutes and then get an error in the client.